# Bootstrap - Responsive websites

Tags: responsive-design

I was going to look into Bootstrap for developing websites. For those that use it, does Bootstrap do most of the responsive coding for you or makes it any easier?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does include classes to help you build responsive websites. It even includes some nice features for responsive navigation bars, etc. So yes it does make it a lot easier to build responsive websites.

I would suggest to just have a look at the docs. You can start [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/) and [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) and see if you like it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I just took a look and already it seems that my life will be easier with Bootstrap. I'm going to look further into this. Thanks again.